# For Zamora Spain where can I find the official local public holidays?

Tags: spain, public-holidays

For [Zamora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zamora%2C_Spain) in Spain, I need to get the list of official **local** public holidays. So not national public holidays and not regional public holidays. I need the list of public holidays for Zamora.

According to [this](https://comunicacion.jcyl.es/web/jcyl/Comunicacion/es/Plantilla100Detalle/1284721258206/NotaPrensa/1285094765138/Comunicacion) site there should be 2.

> Estas doce fiestas se establecen sin perjuicio de **las dos fiestas** de carácter local que habrán de determinarse por la autoridad competente para cada municipio, conforme a lo establecido en el artículo 46 del Real Decreto 2001/1983, de 28 de julio, sobre regulación de jornadas de trabajo, jornadas especiales y descansos.

[calendarios.ideal.es](https://calendarios.ideal.es/laboral/castilla-y-leon/zamora/zamora) says the 2 days are the Monday 6 June (called "La Hiniesta") and Wednesday 29 June 2022 (called "San Pedro"). Screenshot below.
[image]

But [www.calendarioslaborales.com](https://www.calendarioslaborales.com/calendario-laboral-zamora-2022.htm) only mentions the Wednesday 29 June. Screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the [official anouncement](http://www.diputaciondezamora.es/recursos/doc/LaProvincia/FiestasyRomerias/46839_2512512022103745.pdf) of the Zamora province government for the year 2022. As you can see there, there are no bank holidays on June, so these 2 days mentioned in June, must be local bank holidays only in certain cities (I presume that they refer to the capital, also called Zamora).

Answer (score 1):

The official 2022 holiday lists for each local municipality can be found in the [Official Bulletin](https://estaticos-cdn.prensaiberica.es/epi/public/content/file/original/2021/1210/11/consulta-las-fechas-de-las-fiestas-de-tu-pueblo-en-2022-213d124.pdf) for the province of Zamora (December 10, 2021, from page 7).

For the municipality of Zamora, both 6th and 29th of June are listed.